# Create a batch script with cluster.exe for MS SQL Failover AOAG

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, failovercluster

I want to create a batch script using cluster.exe

My initial batch script(**FAILOVER_TO_DRDB01.BAT**) is:

```
ECHO ON
cluster.exe node DRDB01 /status  -o  C:\FAILOVER_TO_DRDB01_LOG.txt
```

When I try to run it, there is no output created.

My main goal is that it will output this:

```
Listing status for node 'DRDB01':

Node           Node ID Status
-------------- ------- ---------------------
DRDB01               3 Joining
```

Once it sees that Status is **Joining**, it will run the following script:

```
net.exe stop clussvc  
net.exe start clussvc /forcequorum
```

And once it failover, it will run the script below:

```
cluster.exe node DRDB01 /prop nodeweight=1 /prop:NodeWeight /status
cluster.exe node PDCDB01 /prop nodeweight=0 /prop:NodeWeight /status
cluster.exe node PDCDB02 /prop nodeweight=0 /prop:NodeWeight /status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to find the node **up** at the end

```
@(setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
  echo off 
  set "DRNode=DRDB01"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  CALL :End
  EXIT /B 0
)

:Main
  REM Loop Until the status of the cluster node indefinitly:

  CALL :Do_Until_Status "%DRNode%" "Joining"

  CALL :Restart_Cluster_Svc

  CALL :Do_Until_Status "%DRNode%" "Up"

  CALL :On_Status_Up

GOTO :EOF


:Do_Until_Status
    cluster.exe node %~1 /status
    cluster.exe node %~1 /status | FIND /I "%~1" | FIND /I "%~2" && ( GOTO :EOF)
GOTO :Do_Until_Status

:Restart_Cluster_Svc

  REM stop the cluster service and start it using force quorum
  net.exe stop clussvc  
  net.exe start clussvc /forcequorum  

GOTO :EOF

:On_Status_Up
  cluster.exe node DRDB01 /prop nodeweight=1 /prop:NodeWeight /status
  cluster.exe node PDCDB01 /prop nodeweight=0 /prop:NodeWeight /status
  cluster.exe node PDCDB02 /prop nodeweight=0 /prop:NodeWeight /status
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks man, if it already up, how will i skip the the 
:Restart_Cluster_Svc